# select globalmap using tDBinput with Talend give the error: Invalid character constant

Tags: sql, global, talend, converters, invalid-characters

I have to remove the accents from the person's name, but I cannot apply the function in Talend while it works in SQL oracle.

this query works in my tDBInput component :

```
"SELECT  '"+((String)globalMap.get("copyOfSORTIE.NOM"))+"' as nom_nom_compl,
         '"+((String)globalMap.get("copyOfSORTIE.ENTETE"))+"' entete
FROM DUAL"
```

However, when I want to add the convert function, it doesn't work

this query does not work :

```
"SELECT  '"+((String)globalMap.get(CONVERT("copyOfSORTIE.NOM",'US7ASCII')))+"' as nom_nom_compl,
         '"+((String)globalMap.get("copyOfSORTIE.ENTETE"))+"' entete
FROM DUAL"
```

In my talend :

[image]

I am getting this error

[image]

What is the syntax for it to work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Two things there :

- I don't know the CONVERT method, but I can see that you are applying it to the key of your globalMap variable , and not the value (as if you wanted to convert "myKey" and not "myValue" which is attached to the key). Are you sure this is what you want to achieve ? if not, the syntax should be something similar to `"SELECT  CONVERT('"+((String)globalMap.get("copyOfSORTIE.NOM"))+"','US7ASCII') "`
- A useful java method implemented in talend is `TalendString.removeAccents("")` that you can apply directly on your talend variable, thus not using a SQL method.